# При отправке формы отследить на какую кнопку нажали и передать через ajax на сервер

Tags: javascript, ajax, form, click

HTML

```
<form action="" id="select">
  <p class="select__title">Способ оплаты</p>
  <div class="select-btns">
    <button class="select-btn" id="pay-lk">Баланс лк</button>
    <button class="select-btn" id="pay-home">При получений</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS/JQuery

```
$("#select").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const totalPrice = parseFloat(total.textContent);
    if (totalPrice === 0) {
      return;
   } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pay.php',
        data: {
          totalPrice: totalPrice,
          products: cart
        },
        success: function (response, statusText, status) {
          // console.log('Запрос успешно отправился, получаем ответ', response);
          balance.innerHTML = parseFloat(response);
          products.textContent = '';
          total.textContent = '0 Р';
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Через `$(e.currentTarget)` обращайся к кнопке

На тебе еще рефактор:

```js
$('#select').on('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const totalPrice = parseFloat(total.textContent);
    if(!totalPrice || totalPrice === 0)return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pay.php',
        data: {
            totalPrice: totalPrice,
            button_class: $(e.currentTarget).attr('class'),
            button_id: $(e.currentTarget).attr('id'),
            products: cart
        },
        success: (response)=>{
            // console.log('Запрос успешно отправился, получаем ответ', response);
            balance.innerHTML = parseFloat(response);
            products.textContent = '';
            total.textContent = '0 Р';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Igor что (..........)

Comment: Я для Вас вывел в своем примере `e.currentTarget.id` в сабмите.

Comment: @Igor мы видим, и?

Comment: ... и чему он равен?

Comment: @Igor что тебе нужно

Comment: @Igor и к чему этот шиттолкинг тада, кулсторибоб