# JQuery как скрыть все элементы кроме одного

Tags: javascript, jquery, for, hide

Я пытался сделать так, но выводит ошибки. Подскажите мне, как это написать под Jquery

```
const blocks = $('.blocks');
for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks[i].hide();
  blocks[i].click(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle();
  });
}
```

Comment: "но выводит ошибки" - ???

Comment: @Igor То что не существует функций hide, но если сделать $('.blocks).hide(), то все работает

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1129352, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1123421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks.eq(i).hide();
  ...
```

---

Цикл не нужен:

```
$('.blocks').hide().click(function() {
  $(this).slideToggle();
});
```